# subtract current time from pandas date column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like

```
x = pd.DataFrame(['05/06/2015 00:00', '22/06/2015 00:00', None], columns=['myDate'])
```

I want to find out the number of days between the dates in the `myDate` column and the current date. How can I do this? I tried the below without much success

```
pd.to_datetime(x['myDate']) - pd.datetime.now().date()
```

Comment: could you post pandas, numpy version, also please try my last snippet it works fine for me, also when you say doesn't work, please show any errors and the output/result that didn't work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the following works for me:

```
In [9]:

df = pd.DataFrame(['05/06/2015 00:00', '22/06/2015 00:00', None], columns=['myDate'])
df['myDate']= pd.to_datetime(df['myDate'], errors='coerce')
df
Out[9]:
      myDate
0 2015-05-06
1 2015-06-22
2        NaT
In [10]:

df['diff'] = df['myDate'] - pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()
df
Out[10]:
      myDate    diff
0 2015-05-06  9 days
1 2015-06-22 56 days
2        NaT     NaT
```

As does your version:

```
In [13]:

df['diff'] = df['myDate'] - pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()
df
Out[13]:
      myDate    diff
0 2015-05-06  9 days
1 2015-06-22 56 days
2        NaT     NaT
```

A more compact version:

```
In [15]:

df = pd.DataFrame(['05/06/2015 00:00', '22/06/2015 00:00', None], columns=['myDate'])
df['diff']= pd.to_datetime(df['myDate'], errors='coerce') - pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()
df
Out[15]:
             myDate    diff
0  05/06/2015 00:00  9 days
1  22/06/2015 00:00 56 days
2              None     NaT
```

Comment: Thanks - that coerce keyword is useful :)

Comment: that coerce keyword doesn't exist

Comment: Just updated syntax above for the latest `pandas` version