# Games Since in last win python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

```
Date         HomeTeam    isWin 
10/23/2015   United      1
01/04/2016   United      0
03/25/2016   United      1
04/14/2016   United      1
04/14/2016   Turk        1
04/15/2016   Turk        1
```

I have a dataframe in pandas like above. I want to create a calculated column called GamesSinceLastWin that calculates the games since the hometeam last won. How would i do this exactly?

I've tried this but doesnt seem to work

```
df.loc[:,'GSLW'] = df.groupby('HomeTeam').HomeWin.transform(lambda x : (x == 0).expanding().sum())
```

Comment: Hint: use `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')` to change the column to datetime object

Comment: days since today?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901993/subtract-current-time-from-pandas-date-column

Comment: I updated my question and what i've tried

Comment: Given your sample data, could you post a sample of what you expect the outcome to look like? i.e. Would `04/14/2016` for `United` be 2 or 1? Does "since last won" include that day of?